# getting data from XML using asp.net Vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<GateDocument>
<!-- The document's features-->
<GateDocumentFeatures>
<Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">MimeType</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">text/html</Value>
</Feature>
</GateDocumentFeatures>

<!-- The document content area with serialized nodes -->

<TextWithNodes><Node id="0" />astralis<Node id="8" /> <Node id="9" />ltd<Node id="12" />
<Node id="14" />{<Node id="15" />DOCUMENT<Node id="23" />}<Node id="24" /> <Node id="25" />{<Node id="26" />TYPE<Node id="30" />}<Node id="31" />EX-<Node id="34" />10<Node id="36" />.<Node id="37" />12<Node id="39" /> <Node id="40" />{<Node id="41" />SEQUENCE<Node id="49" />}<Node id="50" />3<Node id="51" /> <Node id="52" />{<Node id="53" />FILENAME<Node id="61" />}<Node id="62" />e<Node id="63" />300201<Node id="69" />_<Node id="70" />ex<Node id="72" />10<Node id="74" />-<Node id="75" />12<Node id="77" />.<Node id="78" />txt<Node id="81" /> <Node id="82" />{<Node id="83" />DESCRIPTION<Node id="94" />}<Node id="95" />
</TextWithNodes>

<Annotations>
.
.
.
.
.
</Annotations>

<Annotations Name="Original markups">
.
.
.
.
</Annotations>

</GateDocument>
```

I have loaded this XML in XMLDocument using vb.net/asp.net. I need data between Nodes with id > 16 and Id < 30 that is  "}{TYPe}" Please note that It is not attribute's value. It is data between nodes. I created following code but It is very slow.

```
   Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
            Dim document As New XPathDocument(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/gate_xml_output.xml"))
            Dim navigator As XPathNavigator = document.CreateNavigator()
            Dim iterator As XPathNodeIterator = navigator.Select("//TextWithNodes/node()[preceding-sibling::Node[@id=" & startNode & "] and following-sibling::Node[@id=" & endNode & "]]")


            While iterator.MoveNext()
                sb.Append(iterator.Current.Value & " ")
            End While
```

May be I need to modify following code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<TextWithNodes>...</TextWithNodes");

string result = string.Join(" ",
    doc.Root
       .Nodes()
       .SkipWhile(n => n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element ||
                       (int)((XElement)n).Attribute("id") != 16)
       .TakeWhile(n => n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element ||
                       (int)((XElement)n).Attribute("id") != 30)
       .OfType<XText>());

// result == "pet DOCUMENT"
```

What I need to supply to XDocument.Parse.

Please suggest.

Comment: is there any reason you are not using linq to xml?

Comment: I want to use it. actually the last solution is in linq to XML but It need to be modified. Please suggest LINQ to XML solution. I prefer that.

Comment: @linkerro  this is just a range. you can use any other number. Thanks. badly need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the range 15 to 30

```
  XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
  var firstElement = xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "Node" && x.Attribute("id").Value=="15").FirstOrDefault();
  var lastElement = xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "Node" && x.Attribute("id").Value == "30").FirstOrDefault();
  var response = firstElement.NodesAfterSelf().Where(x => lastElement.NodesBeforeSelf().Contains(x));
```

This returns the elements. You can get the contents with ToString()

Comment: Do I need to use response.tostring to get the contents betweeen node elements ?

Comment: The query returns all the nodes that are situated between the nodes with id 15 and 30 (not including). If you want the exact string content add a Select(x=>x.ToString()) to the query and the concatenate the strings.

Comment: @inkerro: I tried this:   Dim response = firstElement.NodesAfterSelf().Where(Function(x) lastElement.NodesBeforeSelf().Contains(x)).Select(x >= x.ToString) but it is giving error.

Comment: Dim response = firstElement.NodesAfterSelf().Where(Function(x) lastElement.NodesBeforeSelf().Contains(x)).Select(function(x)x.ToString)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying is how to use `XDocument.Parse`

Because your XML is in an external file by the looks of it you are better off using

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("myXmlFile.xml");
```

Then proceeding as the sampel with the LINQ to XML. Apologies if I have misunderstood